# Decision tree with final text out put

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make a simple membership structure, where the person select a location and based on the location they can choose a membership type, and from there they can go and pay. I have searched High up and low down, but I cant find something that suits my needs. when I get the code functioning I will be putting it into a page on wordpress

JSfiddle attempt: https://fiddle.jshell.net/nemothefish/05fz3Lc3/

I'm hoping to have a 3 box layout, the solution doesn't have to use jQuery objects, it just has to have one button that leads to another and displays a final result

```
| Location Choice | Membership type | result                    |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Location 1      | Person          | Price for membership type | 
| Location 2      | Student         | and location displayed    |
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically just use a `if/else` statement to check which one is clicked and show the relevant next input box.

```js
$(select).on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'your value') {
        $('#your_value').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```